# Is there a way to edit tag colours through the UI?

Tags: tags

Having created a number of tags I've decided it would be useful to have them colour-coded.
It is straightforward to specify a colour when creating a tag, but I can't work out how to apply a colour to an already created tag, and have it stick. The UI lets me specify a colour, but there seems to be no way to save the change?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? AFAIK, you just need to select a value. The color is auto-saved after the dialog box is closed (Same behavior on create and edit screen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the tag to edit, then click on the color rectangle (if white than you will not see any color) . See screeprint [image]

So in this example the color rectangle is the one in the left top hand corner.

Comment: Using Firefox, a colourpicker pops up and lets me specify a colour for the tag. What isn't obvious, especially in the described scenario, where I want to set colours for a whole list of tags, is that I have to close the colourpicker each time to save the change, then move on to the next tag.

Comment: And in the current release of Safari on Mac OSX 'input type="color" isn't supported so you are simply editing hex values.

Comment: Yes unfortunately it's outside the scope of CiviCRM to try to get those browsers to catch up with html5 standards!